# $f(n) + f(f(n)) = 2n + 3$, find all $f(n)$.

Tags: number-theory, functions, contest-math, problem-solving

Find all functions $f$ that maps from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, and $$f(n) + f(f(n)) = 2n + 3$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

---

**Attempt:**

I find a function that is $f_{1}(n) = n+1$, we can easily check $ f_{1}(f_{1}(n)) = n + 2 $, so adding together we always get $2n+3$. So in this case they are consecutive positive integers.

In general for linear function:  $f(n) = An +B$, then $f(f(n)) = A(An+B) + B = A^{2}n + AB + B$, so

$$ f(n) + f(f(n)) = (A + A^{2})n + AB+2B $$

if $A,B$ integers, then the only solution is $A=B=1$.

Another fact is that $f(n) + f(f(n))$ is odd for all natural numbers $n$. This means that $f(n)$ and $f(f(n))$ must have different parity.

I will add something new:

$$ f(f(n)) + f(f(f(n))) = 2f(n)+3 $$

$$ f(f(f(n))) + f(f(f(f(n)))) = 2f(f(n))+3 $$

$$ \vdots $$

$$ F(n, k) + F(n, k+1) = 2F(n, k-1) + 3$$

where $F(n,k) = \underbrace{f(f(f(...(f(n))...)))}_{k}$ if $k \ge 1$, and $F(n, 0) = n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all function satisfying $f(f(n))+f(n)=2n+3k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535189/find-all-function-satisfying-ffnfn-2n3k) - using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(n)%2Bf(f(n))%3D2n%2B3%24&p=1), I actually found [Find, with proof, all functions $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N, f(n) + f(f(n)) = 2n+3$.](/q/3880510/602049) instead, which has no undeleted answer and was closed as a duplicate of the proposed duplicate question.

Comment: Also, FYI, I found several AoPS threads, e.g., [functional equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1357104p7426180), [2014 Algebra B2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c140h615248p3661617) (this one has a relatively simple & straightforward proof), and the related [Funtional equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1347479p7341817) which deals with $R \to R$ instead and explains there are infinitely many solutions in that case.